# How to deslect highlighted text in textbox if already highlighted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

So I have this very simple JS function that selects all the text in the ASP.NET texbox (input):

```
function selectAllText(textbox) {
    textbox.focus();
    textbox.select();
}
```

..and it gets called like this on the click event:

```
$("#<%=Textbox1.ClientID %>").click(function () { selectAllText(jQuery(this)) });
```

The problem is no matter how many times a user clicks in the text box *all of the text* is always selected. I understand why this is occuring (based on the way my code above is), but it doesn't work well when the user tries to click in the middle of a word to get the cursor back to make a modification to the text.

How do I modify this JS to tell if the text is already highlighted and then deselect the text? This was on subsiquient click, the user can get the single cursor on a precise clicked location to make a modification.

I am trying to get the documentation on the `.select()` method to see if I could do `if(!textbox.select())`, but I am having a hard time finding it, so post any doc links as well if you have them.

**EDIT:** This problem and need for a workaround seems to be for IE (I am using IE9). In Chrome the behavior by default is what I need, but this is for an intranet application that runs on IE, so it appears I need an explicit workaround.

Thanks!

Comment: It took me too much time to handle that IE crap that I gave up. +1 for the hard mission... sorry that I couldn't help you more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it necessary to do the .focus() in this function? You could instead attach a simple .select(); to the onfocus event (`.bind('focus', function(){..})`): http://jsfiddle.net/EGHzj/

Comment: That worked! binding to the focus event instead worked better as you posted. It works as expected in IE. Now the real solution would be to somehow combine all of these samples together for a working IE,Chrome,FF,Safari example...

Comment: I can't really imagine binding to onfocus not working in any of the other browsers. Especially since you're relying on jQuery's functions which usually take care of cross-browser compatibility as best possible.

Comment: Yeah you would think but try your http://jsfiddle.net/EGHzj/ example in Chrome. It does not work. However I needed a fix for IE and it worked so technically a done deal!

Comment: That's indeed surprising, I'm wondering if it's actually the binding that doesn't work or whether `.select()` doesn't cover for Chrome. But that's a different topic I think :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').bind('click',function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        }else{
           this.focus();
           this.select(); 
           $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        }  
    });
});
```

This should work in IE also,
http://jsfiddle.net/rAqgw/7/

Comment: I am testing it in IE9 and everytime I click in the box, *everything* is selected. It never becomes a single cursor for me. In Chrome it did work. Let me modify my OP to state this.

Comment: also in FF 11.0, every time everything gets selected

Comment: Also, in Chrome the second click works but all subsequent clicks select all. The behavior isn't very nice. After initial focus subsequent clicks shouldn't select all I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

```
function selectAllText(textbox) {
    // if there isn't selected text.
    if (textbox[0].selectionEnd) {
        textbox.focus();
        textbox.select();
    }
}

$('#txt').click(function() {
    selectAllText($(this));
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SyAf6/4)
    ​

Comment: On this line: `if (window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).collapsed)` I get a "Object doesn't support this property or method` error.

Comment: @atconway. Working fine for me! can someone confirm the error? what browser are you using?

Comment: Also in the live demo, the text for me never gets selected regardless of number of clicks (IE9).

Comment: I had added an 'EDIT' section to my OP a bit late about this being with IE. I see it *does* work in Chrome.

Comment: Not working in FF11, the text always gets completely selected. 
"uncaught exception: [Exception... "Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount"  ...]

Comment: @Armatus. Try the updated answer. it's working fine, isn't it?

Comment: It's not throwing an error in the console anymore but the behaviour is the same :)

Comment: Regardless, for the answer I need a solution for IE please. @Gordon, try your solution in IE9; it does not work.

Comment: @Gordon - thanks for the continued effort, but I tried your latest version in IE9 and it never selects the text.

Comment: @atconway. Sorry mate, I give up. **I hate `IE` it's so bad**

Comment: @gdoron - you deserve a lot of credit for the effort, but it still wasn't working just right in IE. I don't blame your for your sentiments on IE! :P However the good news is, using your solution combined with the solution from @ Armatus is *pretty close*.